# Django async testing: Cannot operate on a closed database

Tags: django, pytest

I was following [this tutorial](https://testdriven.io/courses/real-time-app-with-django-channels-and-angular/part-one-websockets-part-one/) on testdriven.io in order to test some async functions in django and I need to add som decorators in order to enable my async tests to access to the DB.
However, I get the following error message:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-KucV-wUh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 237, in _cursor
    return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
  File "/Users/apple/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-KucV-wUh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 274, in create_cursor
    return self.connection.cursor(factory=SQLiteCursorWrapper)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database.
```

---

```
@database_sync_to_async
def create_user():
    user = User.objects.create(
        username='username',
    )
    user.set_password('password')
    user.save()




@pytest.mark.asyncio
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
class WebsocketTests(TestCase):

    async def test_not_authenticated(self):
        await create_user()
        ..... other async functions
```

Comment: Can you try not inheriting from `TestCase`? I believe `pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)` setups up a TransactionTestCase.

Comment: ```
class WebsocketTests:

    async def test_not_authenticated(self):
        await create_user()
```
I removed it and now `manage.py test` can't recognize that I have a test here.

Comment: Does `pytest` catch it?

Comment: I think not, Also, it shows
```
PytestUnknownMarkWarning: Unknown pytest.mark.django_db - is this a typo?  You can register custom marks to avoid this warning - for details, see https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/mark.html
    @pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
```

Comment: Do you have `pytest-django` installed?

Comment: it still can't recognize the test without inheriting from `TestCase`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235970/discussion-between-ali-al-karaawi-and-schillingt).

Answer (score 3):

1. make sure to `pip install pytest pytest-django pytest-asyncio
2. use `@pytest.mark.asyncio` and `@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)`

```py
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async


@database_sync_to_async
def MakeMessage():
    Message.objects.create()

@pytest.mark.asyncio
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
class TestWebSocket:

    async def test_connection(self, settings):
          communicator = WebsocketCommunicator( application=application, path=path )
          connected, _ = await communicator.connect()
          assert connected
         m = await sync_to_async(Message.objects.count)()
         assert m == 0
         await MakeMessage()
         m = await sync_to_async(Message.objects.count)()
         assert m == 1
```

```py
#settings.py
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'frosty_breeze_25125.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'frosty_breeze_25125.asgi.application'

host = os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379') if IS_DEPLOYED else ('0.0.0.0', 6379)
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [host],
        },
    },
}

REDIS_URL = [host]
```

Comment: Thanks! I had neglected to add the `transaction=True`, and it was the missing piece to get my tests running.